# Assignment of "double?" using "?" operator not possible?

Tags: c#

I try to use the following code

```
double d;
double? a = double.TryParse("3.14", out d) ? d : null;
```

But it won't compile as "there is no implicit conversion between double and null'. Splitting up the code above as follows works:

```
        double d;
        double? a;
        if ( double.TryParse("3.14", out d))
            a = d;
        else
            a = null;
```

How come there is a difference when using the ?-operator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, that you can't assign `null` to a `double` and your ternary expression returns a `double`, not a `double?`. Because `null` doesn't have an implicit type, the return type of your ternary expression is determined by the part, that *has* an implicit type, that is the part that returns `d`. As `d` is a `double`, your whole ternary expression evaluates to returning a `double`.

Fix it by casting either one of the returns to `double?`, e.g.

```
double d;
double? a = double.TryParse("3.14", out d) ? (double?)d : null;
```

Comment: The reasoning in this answer is close but slightly incorrect. It would be more accurate to say that the ternary expression doesn't return any type; **the error is actually that a consistent return type cannot be inferred.**

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for the correction. If this is the case, IMHO, the compiler message is also slightly incorrect. Because it suggests that `null` should be converted to `double`. If no type could have been inferred, the compiler couldn't know which type `null` should be converted to.

Comment: @Daniel: Here's the thing: first we make a list of the possible types. In this case, that list consists only of "double". Then we remove from the list any type that both operands are not convertible to. In this case, that makes the list empty. So what is the error reported? The list became empty because null is not convertible to double, so that is the error reported. That said, I'm not super thrilled with the error message here either.

Answer (score 2):

You could cast `null` to `double?` on the right hand side of the null coalescing operator to indicate to the compiler the desired return type:

```
double? a = double.TryParse("3.14", out d) ? d : (double?)null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, where you explicitly cast the null

```
double? a = double.TryParse("3.14", out d) ? d : (double?)null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the null has to be castable to the type of d (double in this case) as well as the type of a

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast `d` to `double?`.

Try `a = double.TryParse("3.14", out d) ? (double?) d : null;`